# Convert a String format to

Tags: java, date

I want to create a parser program. Every two characters in string will cut into a unit of time, for example: "150901184610801" need to be converted to displayed as "Tue Sep 01 18:46 CST 2015".

I know my question is somewhat complex, so I would like to be divided into different blocks sequentially solve the problem.

The first problem is:

How to use JAVA to format string follow a rule : each two word element cut into a variable, so I can manipulate variables such as yy (15), mm (09), dd (01), hh (18), ss (46).

Thanks again for any suggest.

Comment: Have a look at `SimpleDateFormat`.  Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse your text into a `Date` object and then use another to format to your specifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually seems quite simple:

```
String s = "150901184610801";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddhhmmssS");
System.out.println(df.parse(s));
```

OUTPUT:

```
Tue Sep 01 18:46:10 CEST 2015
```

Check [SimpleDateFormat API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Dear Jordi, Thanks again for your kind support : ),  this issue toss me a whole day.

Comment: Great to hear this @CodeLife that is SO made for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)